# SQL Server CE exists clause performance

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

The following query runs very slow when running the sql against a SQL Server CE database, I had hoped to translate it to linq for EF. Can anyone advise on this, I haven't created any indexes on SQL Server CE yet. Table2 has 100,000 rows.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Table1 T1a
WHERE
    EXISTS
(
SELECT
    NULL
FROM
    Table2 T2
        JOIN Table1 T1b ON T2.Field1 = T2.Field1
WHERE
    T2.SomeID = 12345 AND
    T1a.SomeString = T1b.SomeString
)
ORDER BY
    T1a.SomeString,
    T1a.AnotherString
```

Comment: "I haven't written indexes" - That's the problem then. You need indexes to get better performance.

Comment: Just the same as in SQL Server then?  Any obvious ones in this query?

Comment: Did you mean to write `JOIN Table1 T1b on T2.Field1 = T1b.Field1` above??  The way it's currently written `T2.Field1=T2.Field1` is the same as join on 1=1.

Comment: Yes.  It's definitely quicker now, just wasn't sure how to proceed with SQL CE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering ONLY the information given.

To me `T2.SomeID` would be the most obvious place to start with an index.  After that you might look at `T2.Field1` because of it's use in the join (and possibly `T1.Field1` depending on the # of rows in `T1`).  The next one is likely going to be `T1.SomeString` both for it's comparison usage and because it's being used in a sort.

Other than `T2.SomeID` however it kind of depends on the makeup of your data, the cardinality of each value, how many rows are in the tables, how many other queries there are.  How many updates vs lookups will be done etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks.  Table2 has 250,000 rows and Table1 has 1500.  This is mainly the only query and no updates required.